# Meaning of black dot punctuation and と in this sentence

Tags: grammar, particle-と

> 安請け合いする男•友蔵と、裏切る可能性のあるヒロシ。

I'm struggling to piece together this sentence. I have 安請け合いする男 (a man who makes promises without enough thought) and 裏切る可能性のあるヒロシ (Hiroshi who has the potential to betray *someone*).

I don't know what the • is doing and I'm not sure about the と. And, of course, the sentence ends in a noun for extra confusion.

My best guess is that • is equivalent to の, と means "along with" and the sentence implicitly ends in だ. Putting that together I get:

> This is Hiroshi who has the potential for betraying *someone* along with/like Tomozou, a man who makes promises without thinking.

Not at all confident about this.

Comment: 安請け合いする男(友蔵) and 裏切る可能性のあるヒロシ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That dot is used to express apposition ([examples](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/80484/5010)). A comma is much more common for this purpose, but a 中黒 may be used like this, too.

This と is just "and" here. It joins two people; "(such-and-such) Tomozo and (such-and-such) Hiroshi".